# Unable to debug PHP API from an Android Client

Tags: php, android

I am trying to debug my PHP API (XDebug + PHPStorm configurated and working correctly) calling it from an Android application.

I have enabled remote debug in PHPStorm and if I do a request from, for example, Postman, PHP Storm stops on the selected breakpoints. 
However, when the Android app (in debug mode) do a request to php server (with PHPStorm opened), the Android app gets the response but it does not stop on breakpoints.

Why?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need your Android application to make requests with the XDebug cookie set. This, in case you've configured XDebug to allow debugging from different IP addresses other than the local Development Box.